# Управление памятью в objective C

Tags: objective-c, память

Я прошла туториал, но не до конца поняла, когда что использовать... Я имею ввиду retain & release / autorelease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

retain - возвращает id, например, требует от obj увеличить счётчик ссылок и выполнить действие setBlabla.

```
[[obj retain] setBlabla:blabla]
```

release - освобождение памяти, уменьшение числа ссылок, когда id = 0 вызывается dealloc.

autorelease - планирует вызов метода release в будующем.