# Что значит retain в объявлении проперти?

Tags: objective-c

Прочитал, как могут параметризоваться проперти в Objective-C. С параметрами readonly, assign и copy все понятно. С nonatomic - не очень (вроде как аналог volatile в Java?), а вот с retain совсем плохо. Не могу понять, в каком случае мне надо использовать именно retain? В [теме про управление памятью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922) написано, что "требует увеличить счётчик ссылок". То есть если у нас retain стоит в объявлении проперти, то при каждом обращении к ней обязательно увеличивается счетчик ссылок (непонятно, зачем это надо тогда)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`retain`, в отличие от `copy` не копирует объект при обращении к свойству, а увеличивает счетчик использований и возвращает тот же самый объект (как бы ссылку на объект). Это нужно, если объект большой или его не имеет смысла копировать. Например, объекты типа `UIView`, `UIViewController`, `UIWindow`.

Ключевое словом nonatomic означает, что при генерации реализаций сеттера и геттера (`@synthesize`) компилятор не будет вставлять блокировки для корректного обращения к свойству из разных потоков. То есть nonatomic означает "потоконебезопасный". nonatomic в большинстве случаев предпочтителен, т. к. сеттер и геттер работают быстрее.

Comment: получается, retain - передача по ссылке, copy - по значению.

Comment: Да, так и есть.